# Why using "head(filename)" command in R (Jupyter notebook) only returns the first row of a file that has multiple rows and columns?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, head

I have written "a" into a CSV file. Then Read the CSV file into another variable. When I use head command on this variable I get only the first row as return. But same command on "a" gives the normal return! Why?

[image]

Comment: You may need to use `col.names` in the `write.csv()` function to indicate that the first row of that matrix object `a` should be treated as column. Also, the `dim()` returning 723 rows and 1 columns should have been a great hint that your `a` object was not intended saved as / written from a csv in the intended way.  Better way to get help is to paste your code and a reproducible sample because part of your code is cut off in the image.

Comment: Thank you. Upon close scrutiny I found a typo in my command. In the last read.csv I had ";" as sep not ",". That was messing things up.